# Selenium Web-table java.lang.IndexOutofBoundsException: Index: 1,size: 1

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I need to get the Select Tag  and Input Tag in web table for this I created the below code to get the Tag name in web table.

For this

1. Created a List of Elements  to get the Number of rows in table.
2. For declare the variable as "i" to looping.
3. Find the Select tag in each row to sent the inputs in table.if the select tag presence in row pass the input value else pass different value in web table.

```
// web Table
WebElement table =d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-grid']/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody"));
List<WebElement> trcount = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
int size = trcount.size();
System.out.println(size);

//Using size created the for loop to find each row available in table.
 for(int i=1;i<size;i++) {

//Declare the Xpath to find the particular row              
By tag = By.xpath("(//*[@id='ui-grid']/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/span/select)["+i+"]");
By Input_tag = By.xpath("(//*[@id='ui-grid']/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/span/input)["+i+"]");
List<WebElement> tdcount = trcount.get(i).findElements(tag);
String tag1 = tdcount.get(i).getTagName();
System.out.println(tag1);

 if(tag1.equals("select")){
d.findElement(By.xpath(tag))Select level = new Select(d.FindElement(tag));
level.selectByVisibleText("YES");

 }else {
d.findElement(Input_tag).sendKeys("12");

                }

    }
```

---

Expected Result:
    If Web table presence Select tab then value selected from dropdown else Input Tag presence value should be passed.

Actual Result:
     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: change to `for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {`  In Java arrays/lists are 0 based

Comment: Ya tryed too i=0 still same error getting. java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: you do not evaluate the size of `tdcount` before doing `tdcount.get(i).getTagName();` - it could be empty

Comment: I feel the issue is in :By tag = By.xpath("(//*[@id='ui-grid']/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/span/select)["+i+"]");
By Input_tag = By.xpath("(//*[@id='ui-grid']/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/span/input)["+i+"]");   
Are you sure, these are correct or can you share the snapshots of what you are doing.

Comment: I have updated my answer. consider accepting if it works for you, ask for clarification otherwise

Comment: @Neha - Syntax are correct. I just realign the loop condition.   Please reference below my answer to get the clarity on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Get the number of count in web table. 
WebElement table =d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-grid']/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody"));
            List<WebElement> trcount = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
            int size = trcount.size();

            System.out.println(size);

            //Select particular  tag(Select tag)
            List<WebElement> Select = table.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-grid']/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/span/select"));
            int select_size = Select.size();
            System.out.println(select_size);
            //If web table have select tag perfrom below else to catch no search elements exceptions. 
            try{
            for(int j=1;j<=select_size;j++) {
                By tag = By.xpath("(//*[@class='ng-star-inserted']/span/select)["+j+"]");
                System.out.println("Test");

             }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println((e.getMessage()));
            }
            //Select particular  tag(Input tag)
            List<WebElement> Select1 = table.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-grid']/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/span/input"));
            int select_input = Select1.size();
            System.out.println(select_input);
            try{
            for(int i=1;i<=select_input;i++) {
                By tag1 = By.xpath("(//*[@class='ng-star-inserted']/span/input)["+i+"]");

                System.out.println("Test");

                d.findElement(tag1).sendKeys("12345");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                //d.findElement(Accept_button).click();

            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println((e.getMessage()));
            }
```

Comment: I just realign the for loop condition to get the expect result now.